# drawing lines using polar axis coordinate system in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to draw arrows with polar axis notation in a `pgfplots` figure that has Cartesian axes with the `draw` command:

```
\draw[->] (polar axis cs:radius=1, angle=30) -- (polar axis cs:radius=2, angle=30);
```

I could not find any way to do something like this in the documentation. Are polar coordinates supported in the `axis` environment?

Comment: What should be the reference point (origin) for this notation `axis cs:0,0` ?

Comment: @percusse yes, I would like to define the coordinates with respect to `axis cs:0,0`

Comment: Could you provide a M(N)WE and specify what output you would like to have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a simple workaround you could calculate the coordinates with a bit of trigonometry, which can be put in a macro.
Note that with `compat=1.11` or newer `axis cs` is the default coordinate system. If you have `compat=1.10` or older you need to use `(axis cs:\rtheta{1}{30})`.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\newcommand\rtheta[2]{{#1*cos(#2)},{#1*sin(#2)}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,ymin=-1,ymax=1,xmin=-1,xmax=1]
\draw (\rtheta{0}{0}) -- (\rtheta{1}{30}) -- (\rtheta{1}{120});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]