# Drawing tikz figure over pgfplots(scaling issue)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want draw over a plotted graph. In this particular case I want to show a projectile path hitting a wall(gray box). I want the blue path stop at the gray wall.

May be the coordinates of the `pgfplots` and the coordinates `tikz` uses are not at same scale.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{esvect}

\def\FunctionF(#1){tan(30)*(#1)-(9.8*(#1)^2)/(2*(15*cos(30))^2)}%

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \begin{axis}[
                xmin=0,
                xmax=20,
                ymin=0,
                ymax=4,
                height=4cm,
                width=20cm,
                hide axis
            ]
            \addplot[domain=0:10, samples=500, blue] {\FunctionF(x)};
            \addplot[domain=10:19.883, samples=500, blue, dotted] {\FunctionF(x)};
        \end{axis}
    \draw (-1,0)--(20,0);
    \draw[->] (0,0)--node[above]{$\vv{v}$}(30:3);
        \draw[fill=black, fill opacity=0.2, black] (10,0) rectangle (10.2,3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No, the coordinates of the `tikzpicture` are in general not the same as those of the `axis`. Try to add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}` to the preamble, and move the `\draw`-lines before `\end{axis}`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. In my case after adding ```\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}``` the document is not finishing building. After about 30 minutes it still is building.

Comment: Huh, odd. Don't know why that would happen, and I couldn't even guess without an example demonstrating the behaviour. But nevermind, remove the `compat` setting then, and instead prefix all the coordinates with `axis cs:`. That is, instead of `\draw (-1,0) ...` you have `\draw (axis cs:-1,0) ...`

Comment: Sorry, hadn't noticed the polar coordinate, that might muddle things a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a duplicate of one or more questions, but anyways. The coordinates of an `axis` environment is in general *not* the same as the underlying `tikzpicture`. To draw stuff in axis units, move the stuff inside the `axis` environment and either

- activate `compat=1.11` or some higher version or
- prefix coordinates with `axis cs`. (i.e. `(axis cs:0,0)` instead of `(0,0)`)

The latter doesn't work with polar coordinates though, but a workaround for that is to decompose the vector (e.g. [drawing lines using polar axis coordinate system in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129782)).

You said `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}` stopped your document from compiling, so either try activating it for this single `axis`, by adding it to the options of the environment, or use `axis cs`. Both are demonstrated below.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{esvect}

\def\FunctionF(#1){tan(30)*(#1)-(9.8*(#1)^2)/(2*(15*cos(30))^2)}%

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                compat=1.11, % <-- added
                xmin=0,
                xmax=20,
                ymin=0,
                ymax=4,
                height=4cm,
                width=20cm,
                hide axis
            ]
            \addplot[domain=0:10, samples=50, blue] {\FunctionF(x)};
            \addplot[domain=10:19.883, samples=50, blue, dotted] {\FunctionF(x)};
            
         \draw (-1,0)--(20,0);
         \draw[->] (0,0)--node[above]{$\vv{v}$}(30:3);
         \draw[fill=black, fill opacity=0.2, black] (10,0) rectangle (10.2,3);
        \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                xmin=0,
                xmax=20,
                ymin=0,
                ymax=4,
                height=4cm,
                width=20cm,
                hide axis
            ]
            \addplot[domain=0:10, samples=50, blue] {\FunctionF(x)};
            \addplot[domain=10:19.883, samples=50, blue, dotted] {\FunctionF(x)};
            
         \draw (axis cs:-1,0) -- (axis cs:20,0);
         % can't use polar coordinates directly with axis cs I think, so calculate x- and y-components instead
         \draw[->] (axis cs:0,0) -- node[above]{$\vv{v}$} (axis cs:{3*cos(30)},{3*sin(30});
         \draw[fill=black, fill opacity=0.2, black] (axis cs:10,0) rectangle (axis cs:10.2,3);
        \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```